# Flutter: How to search from FutureBuilder Listview

Tags: firebase, flutter, listview, search

I am new to flutter and trying to finish the last remaining part of my app. I am using Firebase realtime database to store out employee data and listing it using a ListView.builder. I am able to show all the information in the list but I want to implement the search bar. I started off and have it in a controller and shows in the terminal but not sure how to implement it properly to filter the data.

I will past my full code but remove the firebase database as it is open right now for testing.

```html
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:async';
import 'directory_details_screen.dart';

class Directory extends StatefulWidget {
  // const ({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _DirectoryState createState() => _DirectoryState();
}

class _DirectoryState extends State<Directory> {
  TextEditingController _searchController = TextEditingController();

  Future getEmpData() async {
    var response = await http.get(Uri.parse(
        'FIREBASE REMOVED'));
    var jsonData = jsonDecode(response.body);
    List<Employee> employees = [];

    for (var e in jsonData) {
      Employee employee = Employee(
          e["displayName"],
          e["department"],
          e["jobTitle"],
          e["mobilePhone"],
          e["workEmail"],
          e["photoUrl"],
          e["workPhoneExtension"]);
      employees.add(employee);
    }
    print(employees.length);
    return employees;
  }


  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _searchController.addListener(_onSearchChanged);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _searchController.removeListener(_onSearchChanged);
    _searchController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  _onSearchChanged() {
    print(_searchController.text);
  }

  String searchString = "";

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          SizedBox(height: 10),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15.0),
            child: TextField(
              onChanged: (value) {
                setState(() {
                  searchString = value;
                });
              },
              controller: _searchController,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                labelText: 'Search',
                suffixIcon: Icon(Icons.search),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 10),
          Expanded(
            child: FutureBuilder(
              future: getEmpData(),
              builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.data == null) {
                  return Container(
                    child: Center(
                      child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                    ),
                  );
                } else
                  return ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                        return Card(
                          child: ListTile(
                            leading: CircleAvatar(
                              backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                                snapshot.data[i].photoUrl
                              ),
                            ),
                            //leading: Icon(Icons.account_circle),
                            isThreeLine: true,
                            title: Text(snapshot.data[i].displayName,
                                style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                            subtitle: Text("Department: " +
                                snapshot.data[i].department +
                                "\n" +
                                "Title: " +
                                snapshot.data[i].jobTitle),
                            onTap: () {
                              Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                                  builder: (context) => EmployeeDetails(
                                      employee: snapshot.data[i])));
                            },
                          ),
                        );
                      });
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Employee {
  final String displayName,
      department,
      jobTitle,
      mobilePhone,
      workEmail,
      photoUrl,
      workPhoneExtension;
  Employee(this.displayName, this.department, this.jobTitle, this.mobilePhone,
      this.workEmail, this.photoUrl, this.workPhoneExtension);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```dart
...
} else {
final result = _search(snapshot.data);

  return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: result.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, i) {
        return Card(
          child: ListTile(
            leading: CircleAvatar(
              backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                  result[i].photoUrl
              ),
            ),
            //leading: Icon(Icons.account_circle),
            isThreeLine: true,
            title: Text(result[i].displayName,
                style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
            subtitle: Text("Department: " +
                result[i].department +
                "\n" +
                "Title: " +
                result[i].jobTitle),
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) =>
                      EmployeeDetails(
                          employee: result[i])));
            },
          ),
        );
      });
    ...
```

and search method like

```dart
List<Employee> _search(List<Employee>? employee) {
  if(searchString?.isNotEmpty == true) {
    //search logic what you want
    return employee?.where((element) => element.department.contains(searchString))
        .toList() ?? <Employee>[];
  }
  
  return employee ?? <Employee>[];
}
```

Comment: The result list depends on your searchString value. So, when you change your searchString, the list will rebuild and show only searched elements. When you set searchString to an empty value, the result list will contain all elements from snapshot.data. Or maybe you want to search in Firebase realtime database directly?  @BryanS